# Merging Data from 4 SFMC Data Sources into 1 DE

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, sql, datasource

I'm trying to merge various fields from our synced data sources in SFMC.

For `Account_Salesforce`, `Contact_Salesforce`, and `Program_Roster__c_Salesforce`, the relationship is the account ID, but they are named differently in the three data sources.

For `Program_Group__c_Salesforce`, the relationship I am using is the individuals contact ID which is "ID" and matching it to `Program_Group__c` in the `Program_Roster__C_Salesforce` data source.

Here is what I tried, but I'm not great at writing sql.

```SQL
Select 
sm.ID as sm_ID
, cs.AccountID as cs_AccountID
, sm.Name
, sm.Sub_Industry__c
, sm.InsideView_Industry__c
, sm.Industry
, sm.Accreditation_Level__c
, sm.AnnualRevenue
, sm.BillingCity
, sm.BillingState
, sm.Congressional_District__c
, sm.Foreign_Owned__c
, sm.Fortune_Global_500__c
, sm.Fortune_Ranking__c
, sm.Legal_Company_Name__c
, sm.Membership_Level__c
, sm.Membership_Status__c
, sm.MSA_Code__c
, sm.MSA_update__c
, sm.Primary_Business__c
, sm.Ultimate_Parent_Company_Name__c
, sm.Type
, cs.AccountID
, cs.Email
, cs.MailingState
, cs.ID
, pr.program_group__c
, pr.Account_Name__C
, pr.Contact_Name__C
, pr.Program_Group_Name__c
, pg.Department__c
, pg.status__c
, pg.ID
FROM [Account_Salesforce] sm 
Inner JOIN [Contact_Salesforce] cs
ON sm.ID = cs.AccountID
Inner JOIN [Program_Roster__c_Salesforce] pr
ON pr.Account_Name__C = cs.AccountID
Inner Join [Program_Roster__c_Salesforce] pg
On pg.ID = pr.Program_Group__c
```

Comment: What is the problem with the query, are you getting an error?

Comment: Also, think through the DE hierarchy, I doubt you want to inner join all of them. What is the structure of the results you are aiming to get?

Comment: What's the primary key of the target Data Extension?

Comment: Right now I'm sending the the data to a non-sendable DE. I'm just testing things out. Most likely, it will be one of the 18 digit contact IDs.

Comment: I'm not receiving an error, but I'm getting 22+ million results. That doesn't sound right. The Account_Salesforce source has 250k records. The contact_salesforce source has 125k records.

Also, I'm not sure I got the join commands correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, but it’s up to you to understand your data and to know what results you want to get:

```
Select 
sm.ID as sm_ID
, cs.AccountID as cs_AccountID
, sm.Name
, sm.Sub_Industry__c
, sm.InsideView_Industry__c
, sm.Industry
, sm.Accreditation_Level__c
, sm.AnnualRevenue
, sm.BillingCity
, sm.BillingState
, sm.Congressional_District__c
, sm.Foreign_Owned__c
, sm.Fortune_Global_500__c
, sm.Fortune_Ranking__c
, sm.Legal_Company_Name__c
, sm.Membership_Level__c
, sm.Membership_Status__c
, sm.MSA_Code__c
, sm.MSA_update__c
, sm.Primary_Business__c
, sm.Ultimate_Parent_Company_Name__c
, sm.Type
, cs.AccountID
, cs.Email
, cs.MailingState
, cs.ID
, pr.program_group__c
, pr.Account_Name__C
, pr.Contact_Name__C
, pr.Program_Group_Name__c
, pg.Department__c
, pg.status__c
, pg.ID
FROM [Contact_Salesforce] cs 
LEFT JOIN [Account_Salesforce] sm
ON sm.ID = cs.AccountID
LEFT JOIN [Program_Roster__c_Salesforce] pr
ON pr.Account_Name__C = cs.AccountID
LEFT Join [Program_Roster__c_Salesforce] pg
On pg.ID = pr.Program_Group__c
```

In above query, the Contact table is the main table and it’s supplemented with data from other tables. If the logic should be different, please let us know in comments.

Learn more about SQL joins here: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: Thank you. With some adjustments. I was able to get what I needed. I changed the join commands to Inner Join, Right Outer Join, and then Inner Join.